# Adding user of one salesforce org to another salesforce org

Tags: user-admin

I am trying to add user of one salesforce org to be user of another salesforce org . May i know how can i achieve it.

Thanking you.

Comment: I'm not sure,  but maybe single-sign- on between 2 orgs is a possibility.

Comment: if you need to do this only for one user you can do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

you should export the users from the  first Org with Dataloader, Dataloader.IO,etc,.. And then you import they in the new Org.

Comment: You may want to mention that usernames will need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to pass user as value between organisations so I guess you have to just create new user. you of course migrate data by for example CSV - but permissionsSets, GroupMembership will not be migrated. So I guess you have to do this manualy